# Openlayers textbox

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to add some basic text tools to an Openlayers map.

Here is a link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/05jc7ab2/

At the moment I am drawing a rectangle and adding some text on `.on('drawend', func)`. And changing the text when the rectangle is selected.

What I need to figure out is how I can let the user click and edit the text in the rectangle. And have it saved when the text tool in unseleted.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an [overlay](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) (popup) that opens when the feature is selected.
An ol.Overlay is an HTML element that is displayed over the map and attached to a single map location. You can add a from in it to handle text edition and save it as a property of the selected feature.

Comment: Ah I never thought of using the properties, I will give this a go, thanks for the pointer.